# Flutter iOS: Can't detect connected iOS simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, simulator

I run the `flutter doctor` command and it says my Xcode installation is incomplete and no devices detected.

Comment: First of all fix Xcode problem, then update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to reinstall or download Xcode. instead, run the commands:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```

then run `flutter doctor` again.